# jQuery Why i cannot change the radio button value once set

Tags: jquery

Here i got a problem in my script,

Once we set one radio button we cannot change it anymore :

```
$("#divAddNewNote").click(function() {
    if ($("#divAddNewNote textarea").length == 0) {
        $("#divAddNewNote div").css("display", "none");
        box += "<div class=\"noteBottomBar\">";
        box += "    <div class=\"radioPrivatePublic\">";
        box += "        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"groupPrivate\" value=\"private\" /><label for=\"radio1\">Private</label>";
        box += "        <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"groupPrivate\" value=\"public\" /><label for=\"radio2\">Public</label>";
        box += "    </div>";
        box += "    <button onclick=\"ajaxSaveNewStatus(10886);\">Post</button>";
        box += "</div>";
        $("#divAddNewNote").append(box);

        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

});​

It's a problem in my javascript code but i cannot find it

Comment: You should always include the relevant code within your question.  This way if the file/page you are linking to ceases to exist, your question will still remain and could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: It appears that you have rather missed the point of the 4 different jsFiddle panes.

Comment: Yes i agree but the code here is too long, once the bug will be found i will edit my question with the code that caused the problem then ;) sorry about that

Comment: @ MДΓΓ БДLL jsFiddle updated ;)

Comment: sorry about this by the way i posted my question a bit to fast and i didn't pay enough attention to the way i wrote it, it's fixed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your radio buttons are within `#divAddNewNote`.  Your click handler for `#divAddNewNote` returns false.  returning false in a jquery event handler has 2 functions.  It is equivalent to `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`.  The important one here is the `preventDefault`.  This is causing your attempt to change the value of the radio button to be canceled ("prevented").

Comment: i was looking everywhere in my code for an event.stopPropagation or something like that, but i missed the return false.. Too bad i loosed a lot of time on this, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
$('input:radio[name="myradiobutton"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: In your <script type="text/javascript"> block

Answer (score 1):

`$("#radio1").checked = true` is not the correct way to check the radio button programmatically.

Use this `$("#radio1").prop('checked', true)`

Comment: sorry about that i've updated the jsFiddle that's not the problem ;) but thanks for correcting